# ALU implementation w/ ADDER

Tags: logic, vhdl, hdl

Hello I'm trying to create a 32-bit adder with a few opcodes and I've got it working quite well except for two cases and I can't seem to find what's causing them.. Maybe you can help me?

The subtraction case always fails for some reason and the ADDC case fails to compute the correct output when it should be using the carry bit in c_reg that has been created by the ADDS operation.

```
LIBRARY  ieee;
USE  ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY ALU IS 
    GENERIC(WIDTH : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT(Clk    : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
         Reset  : IN STD_LOGIC := '0';
         A      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
         B      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
         Op     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
         Outs   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0));
END ALU;

ARCHITECTURE arch_ALU OF ALU IS

    COMPONENT adder
    PORT(OpA    : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         OpB    : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
         Cin    : IN    STD_LOGIC;
         Cout   : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
         Result : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL adder_output : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    SIGNAL B_neg        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    SIGNAL c_flag   : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    SIGNAL c_reg    : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    SIGNAL cin      : STD_LOGIC := '0';

BEGIN

adder_comp : adder
   PORT MAP(OpA => A,
            OpB => B_neg,
            Cin => cin,
            Result => adder_output,
            Cout => c_flag);        

    WITH Op SELECT 
        B_neg <= NOT(B) WHEN "1000",
                     B  WHEN OTHERS;

    WITH Op SELECT
        cin <= '1'      WHEN "1000", -- SUB
                c_reg   WHEN "0111", -- ADDC
                '0'     WHEN OTHERS; -- ADD/ADDS    

    ALU_Process:
    PROCESS(Clk)
    BEGIN
        IF Reset = '0' THEN
            Outs <= (OTHERS => '0');
        ELSIF rising_edge(Clk) THEN
            CASE Op IS
                WHEN "0001" => Outs <= A AND B;
                WHEN "0010" => Outs <= A OR  B;
                WHEN "0011" => Outs <= A NOR B;
                WHEN "0100" => Outs <= A XOR B;
                WHEN "0101" => Outs <= adder_output; -- ADD 
                WHEN "0110" => Outs <= adder_output; -- ADDS
                    c_reg <= c_flag;    
                WHEN "0111" => Outs <= adder_output; -- ADDC
                WHEN "1000" => Outs <= adder_output; -- SUB
                WHEN "1001" => Outs <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(A) SLL to_integer(UNSIGNED(B(4 DOWNTO 0))));
                WHEN "1010" => Outs <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(A) SRL to_integer(UNSIGNED(B(4 DOWNTO 0))));
                WHEN "1011" => Outs <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(shift_right(SIGNED(A),to_integer(UNSIGNED(B(4 DOWNTO 0)))));
                WHEN OTHERS => Outs <= (OTHERS => '0');
            END CASE;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END arch_ALU;
```

Only the ADDS operation should write it's carry-out to the c_reg and ADDC operation should take the c_reg into account when calculating it's output
The adder is tested and working correctly so the problem is not in the adder design.

First of all I'd like to get to know the problem of the subtraction because it is doing subtraction but the result is a little bit off.. For example:

A   : h'E6A4960F
B   : h'7B494E34
Op  : d'1000
Outs: h'6B5B47DA while it should be h'6B5B47DB

A   : h'EFDE31A3
B   : h'0BCAB8FA
Op  : d'1000
Out : h'E41378BB while should be h'E41378A9

Can you spot my misstake? Cause I certainly can't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the reader can at least test the subtract portions of your design that are present:

```
library  ieee;
use  ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity alu is 
    generic (width:  natural := 32);
    port (
        clk:     in  std_logic := '0';
        reset:   in  std_logic := '0';
        a:       in  std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        b:       in  std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        op:      in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        outs:    out std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0)
    );
end alu;

architecture arch_alu of alu is

--     component adder
--     port (
--          opa:     in    std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0);
--          opb:     in    std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0);
--          cin:     in    std_logic;
--          cout:    out   std_logic;
--          result:  out   std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0)
--     );
-- end component;

    procedure adder (
         signal opa:     in    std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0);
         signal opb:     in    std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0);
         signal cin:     in    std_logic;
         signal cout:    out   std_logic;
         signal result:  out   std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) 
    ) is 
        variable sum:   unsigned (width downto 0);
    begin
        sum := unsigned('0' & opa) + unsigned(opb) + unsigned'(""& cin);
        result <= std_logic_vector(sum (width - 1 downto 0));
        cout <= sum(width);
    end procedure;

    signal adder_output:  std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal b_neg:         std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal c_flag:        std_logic := '0';
    signal c_reg:         std_logic := '0';
    signal cin:           std_logic := '0';

begin

adder_comp:  
    adder
       -- port map (
       (
           opa => a,
           opb => b_neg,
           cin => cin,
           result => adder_output,
           cout => c_flag
       );        

    with op select 
        b_neg <= not b when "1000",
                     b  when others;

    with op select
        cin <= '1'     when "1000", -- sub
                c_reg  when "0111", -- addc
               '0'     when others; -- add/adds    

alu_process:
    process(clk)
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            outs <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            case op is
                when "0001" => outs <= a and b;
                when "0010" => outs <= a or  b;
                when "0011" => outs <= a nor b;
                when "0100" => outs <= a xor b;
                when "0101" => outs <= adder_output; -- add 
                when "0110" => outs <= adder_output; -- adds
                               c_reg <= c_flag;    
                when "0111" => outs <= adder_output; -- addc
                when "1000" => outs <= adder_output; -- sub
                when "1001" => outs <= std_logic_vector (
                    unsigned(a) sll to_integer(unsigned(b(4 downto 0)))
                );
                when "1010" => outs <= std_logic_vector (
                    unsigned(a) srl to_integer(unsigned(b(4 downto 0)))
                );
                when "1011" => outs <= std_logic_vector ( 
                    shift_right(signed(a),to_integer(unsigned(b(4 downto 0))))
                );
                when others => outs <= (others => '0');
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end arch_alu;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity alu_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of alu_tb is
    constant width: integer := 32;
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:   std_logic := '0';
    signal a:       std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal b:       std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal op:      std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal outs:    std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0);
begin 
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 90 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
DUT:
    entity work.alu 
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            a  => a,
            b =>  b,
            op => op,
            outs => outs  
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        a <= x"E6A4960F";
        b <= x"7B494E34";
        op <= "1000";
        wait for 20 ns;
        a <= x"EFDE31A3";
        b <= x"0BCAB8FA";
        wait for 20 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

I wrote a quick and dirty procedure adder.  This eliminates your adder entity/architecture and the component declaration.

I added a simple testbench for the two subtractions, this eliminates your test bench or testing procedure.

And this gives:

[image: alu_tb.png]

And as you can see the results are what you claim as correct.

So what that leaves is either your adder or your testbench (it's a stretch to blame your component declaration).

So what we get from this is that you haven't presented enough information to determine where the error is.

I did this little demonstration because the two errors don't have all the wrong bits in common. If you've tested your adder and are sure of it, it's probably the stimulus input when subtracting.

Comment: Yep thanks for the great response, I have been given the adder and It's said to be tested and verified. I just tested the same design with my ripple carry design and it worked flawlessly. 

I guess I'll have to debugg my adder then :)